# kivy - urllib2 request and regex search metod via G3 network connection

Tags: networking, mobile, connection, urllib, kivy

I am working on kivy for a while and nowadays I am stuck with a problem...

```
try:
        link = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        with open(filename, "w") as file:
            for i in link.readlines():
                duty = re.search('blank">(.*)(\s.*Eczane)', i)
                address = re.search('\w+<br />(.*)</span>', i)
                telephone = re.search('date">(.*)/ \w+', i)
                if duty:
                    s = duty.group(1)
                    file.write(s+" Eczanesi ")
                if address:
                    s = address.group(1)
                    file.write(s+" ")
                if telephone:
                    s = telephone.group(1)
                    file.write(s+" // ")
```

It works well via wireless network connection in my mobile phone (samsung sIII with kivy launcher). However, when I try to connect via g3 network of mobile phone, it doesn't operate the search method, instead it is writing whole website content to file.

What is the problem?

Comment: Which one of the 3 search patterns is doing this, duty address or telephone (or all three so you get the web page contents 3 times in file)?

Comment: yes probably 3 of them is fetching all content, but what i dont get is, why 3g connection affects like that...

Comment: Could it be the encoding is different when browsed from device vs Sim? Try saving the page you receive to a file then compare the two files. If different you'll probably see why regexp doesn't work, if same then issue is likely regexp itself.

Comment: yes you are right, problem is encoding...3g isn't accepting iso8859-9 which is Turkish. it says unknown encoding, probably this is solved in python 3.x but it is a headache in 2.x versions, any suggestion ?

Comment: is the encoding different over the wireless network?

Comment: when i inserted this code    file.write(urllib.urlopen(url).read().decode("iso8859-9").encode("utf-8")), now both wireless and 3g doesnt work, but works perfect on my laptop :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely the encoding used. Maybe it is different on both networks. Regardless, you should probably open the file using that encoding before splitting according to line endings. Also, use the desired encoding when writing:

```
content = urllib.urlopen(url).read().decode("iso8859-9")
with open('film.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in content.split('\n'): # or whatever newline is
        duty = re.search('blank">(.*)(\s.*Eczane)', line)
        ...
        file.write(line.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: yes i already got the point, i will apply the code, thanks for support Scholii

Comment: @oneronur any luck fixing this?

Comment: unfortunatelly no :( but i dont give up :)